# Mine Reporting based on one field and the presence of two values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This is in SQL Server 2005.

I work in a call center, where call records are stored in a History table.  The way the business works, is that an agent (Agent1) takes a call, speaks to the customer then transfers that call to some random second agent (Agent2) for them to close the sale.

In SQL, what the data shows is that the first agent spoke to the customer, and then the call ended with no Disposition.  The second record shows a new call, with a new HistoryID, and it shows Agent1 and Agent2 in the agent field.

Here is an example of how data is laid out:

```
HistoryID| CallID  |   Date                |  Data                   |  Agent  
10940824 | 2149513 | 3/31/2011 12:20:01 PM | Call Data of the Record | agent1  
10940853 | 2149513 | 3/31/2011 12:23:17 PM | Call Data of the Record | agent1 agent2
```

Agent1 & Agent2 would actually be the agents first name, last initial so Agent1 = bobs, Agent2 = annb.  There can be many agents involved, so the names of Agent1 and Agent2 will most likely always be different.

I'm attempting to do some reporting, primarily on the Agent2
Examples of report would be:

How many transfers did Agent2 receive?
Hypothetically, I'd ask SQL to give me a count of all of the History Records where Agent2 is the second person on a record (for a given date, or date range)

> > > > **Adding these possible report scenarios:**
> > > >         Maybe select the record that has the two agents, then select the preceding record where Agent1 exists for the CallID on it's own.  Meaning, I'm working backwards with the data. I ask SQL to find where two values exist in the Agent field, then grab the first agent name and CallID, and fetch the preceding record based on those two values.
> > > >
> > > > Another one would be:
> > > >         I would like to get all the records where there are agent1 and agent2 exist in the Agent field.

If there is any additional information anyone requires for a better answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to create a `VIEW` so you can use it for many other queries:

```
CREATE VIEW CallRecordsAgents AS
( SELECT HistoryID
       , CallID 
       , Date
       , Data
       , LEFT( Agent+' ', CHARINDEX(' ', Agent+' ') - 1)
       AS Agent1
       , RTRIM(LTRIM( 
           SUBSTRING( Agent+' ', CHARINDEX(' ', Agent+' '), LEN(Agent+' '))))
       AS Agent2
  FROM CallRecords
)
```

After that, the question: "***How many transfers did Bob receive?***", would be solved by:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Transfers
FROM CallRecordsAgents 
WHERE Agent2 = "Bob"
```

And "***How many transfers did every agent receive?***", would be:

```
SELECT Agent2
     , COUNT(*) AS TransfersReceived
FROM CallRecordsAgents 
GROUP BY Agent2
```

---

The Agent2 extraction can be simplified (i think) with:

```
       , RTRIM( SUBSTRING( Agent, LEN(Agent1)+2, LEN(Agent) ) )
       AS Agent2
```

Comment: This was very helpful. I'm going to attempt all this, and see how I fare.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Lamak: It may need some more `LTRIM()` manipulations if there are more than one spaces between the agent names or before the first name. I left them out for clarity (if there are, the OP can change the view).

Comment: With 10M rows in the table though, I would prefer to not have a view but add the 2 fields in the table, if possible. Otherwise, the queries that use the view may be real slow.

Comment: @ybercube - They are infact, separated by a single space.  There are no preceding spaces, but there are trailing spaces at the end of the second agent.  Assumedly the program adds the name+space for the agent name regardless of position.

Comment: @ybercube - Must have posted while I was posting.  For the table structure, I don't think there is much I can do with it.  The software program, assumedly writes it's data in to the Agent Column.  If I were to somehow tear at least the second name off and update that into a second column and maybe put on a trigger that would write the second name into the new column?

Comment: If you can add 2 columns on the table, and a trigger that splits the Agent column into these 2, when a new row is added (and one for updates), that would be fine, I think. The triggers could leave the Agent column intact, just to be safe.

Comment: @ybercube - I can leave the Agent column intact.  I would have to either figure out a way to split both names, put them in two new fields or use the Agent column to grab just the first agent, and the new column to contain the second agent.  Then I'll have to post a question on that and on guidance with the trigger! lol Thanks so much for your help - I'm dissecting yours and the other answer's methods to understand exactly how it works.

Comment: @ybercube - Any particular reasons for the changes made to the first example statement of the view creation?

Comment: I added the `RTRIM(` so spaces are trimmed from the right, after the Agent2 part is caught. The `LTRIM(` can be removed if there is always only one space between the two names. But I don't have a 2005 version available now so I can't check (it may be possible to remove the `RTRIM(` too without any side effects. You should check by testing with your data this view or slight modifications to see what's best and faster.

Comment: @ypercube - I tested both examples, the results were the same. Although I noticed a performance deficit using the updated example.  I may be incorrect, but that is simply what I noticed on the first few trials.

Answer (score 2):

Like Abe said, this is a poor database design since you have one field holding two values.  However, I'll assume you cannot change the DB design.  Therefore...

Assuming the table is [CallRecords] and the column containing the agent user IDs is [Agents], then:

```
SELECT *
FROM CallRecords
WHERE (CHARINDEX(' ', Agents, 0) > 0) AND (CHARINDEX(@Agent2UserID, Agents, 0) > CHARINDEX(' ', Agents, 0))
```

Basically, the idea is get all records that have a blank space and have the agent2 ID following the blank space.

Comment: @Abe Miessler - It wouldn't, but the op states that one agent thakes the call and it gets transfered to a second agent to finish the sale, there doesn't seem that another agent would get involved

Comment: That is correct, at least in the database, there is never a third agent written to that field.  It's always had a maximum of two.

Comment: I went ahead and attempted to check this on a particular agent, and it did in fact work!  Here are some results to show performance - In a table of 10949705 records, I ran this on one agent, and returned 884 records with a time of 1m45s.

Comment: And of course in the 42 min since my post, the count is now at 10950993 - difference of 1288 calls. lol.  Lord.  This table just never stops growing.

Comment: @NYSystemsAnalyst - Thank you very much for your response - I awarded the question to ypercube, as he had answered all the questions I had posed.  But, I would like to thank you as your answer was first, and worked just as well for the initial portion.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this would be to **not** store two separate values in one column.  Doing so creates the kind of reporting difficulties that you are talking about.

Fixing this would require restructuring your database and moving the data over.  If you must have two values in one column it is much better to have all of your data in a normalized format and then you can denormalize into views if needed.

As it is, you will need to do some pretty weird stuff to determine that the second value in your varchar column is what you want.  It will also probably kill performance, so if you will ever be dealing with a high volume of data you should look at this sooner rather than later.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not something I can change - as it is how the Call Center software works.  There is no way for me to modify the storing of the agent names.

Answer (score -1):

I would get a count of records grouped by agent2.  something like:

```
SELECT agent2, COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY agent2
```

Comment: Did you read the question?, there is no agent2 column, that's the whole problem, it is merged on the same column that agent1

Comment: I missed the lack of header for agent 2 in the OP.  My apologies.